# How to start with SQL Server SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I want to start with SQL Server SSIS. Kindly guide how to start with it and what are the areas that need to be looked in first.

Comment: Are you talking about installing it, or using it?

Comment: using sql-server ssis...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before diving in and getting your hands dirty start with the basic theory first. You want to be able to provide an answer to the questions "What is SSIS and what is it used for?"

My advice, start at the beginning, read the Microsoft supporting documentation for [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) and develop an overall understanding of the technology and its features.

Another good place to start would be the [Getting Started (Integration Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522535.aspx)

Then why not have a go at some of the [Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522499.aspx) that Microsoft make available.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you type 'SQL Server SSIS Tutorial' into google, or follow this link

http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=sql+server+ssis+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Top result is http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm

Alernatively, document exactly what it is you want to do, and then see if you can find something to help you.

I assunme you have SQL Server installed. 
At the very start, click Start Menu -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -> SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

From in Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) you will be able to create a new SSIS project.

Answer (score 3):

Searching **Google** (or Bing) for "SSIS tutorial" would yield lots of results.....

E.g.

- [SSIS Tutorial: SQL Server 2005 Integration Services Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm)
- [SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) (Introduction)](http://www.mssqltips.com/tutorial.asp?tutorial=200)
- [SSIS Tutorials - Introduction to SSIS Tasks](http://www.ssistutorial.com/)

and **many, many** more...